# How could I connect database and print its contents in a bot message?

Tags: python, sqlite, python-telegram-bot

So, I'm trying to make a bot in Telegram (training for future assignments). I'm using pyTelegramBotAPI and sqlite3, and I've got a question in process. I have created a database (example.db) and an inline button, and now I need to connect this database to a bot, and make it read db's contents (table with a list in it), and print them in message as an answer to a pressed button.
F.E.: Message would be like this: 
"You have a list of things here:
1) Num.1
2) Num.2
.." And a whole list like that.

I'd be glad to hear any advices and code examples, thank you very much.

Comment: whats the status?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an iterative approach:

1. Try go get data from database in format you wish, try to print this
   to terminal. when this works go to step 2.
2. Try to send a test message
   to your telegram bot. when you've got this working go to step 3.
3. Now combine step 1 and step 2, so get data from database and send it to
   bot.
4. Last step is to add button click to above functions you created.